# Monitor the values of two variables at the same time

Tags: front-end, dynamic, monitoring

`Monitor` and `Dynamic` give the possibility to check the value of *one* variable in a program, but is it possible to monitor the values of *two* variables at the same time?

Comment: You can use something like `Dynamic@{a,b,c,d}` to see the values of `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just include both variables. For example:

```
Monitor[Table[Pause[.1]; i + j, {i, 5}, {j, 5}], {i, j}]
```

Animation:

[image]